# How would someone implement version control system in an application for their users, eg. in plnkr.co

Tags: node.js, git, version-control

I am creating an application where each user will have his own workspace which will consist of some text files. He will be editing and saving these files excessively.

I want to implement a version control system for each user to keep track of his work and revert back and forth to any previous version if he wants to.

I would also like users be able to fork into each others workspace to copy the content to their own workspace just like in plnkr.co, make changes and commit easily.

My stack is node.js and angular.js

Where should I start, to implement it. I guess there should some way to use git or some other open source project. Does anybody have any idea what plunker is using?

Answer (score 0):

Super late response, but for anyone stumbling across this, try checking out [git=annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)

We used this at one of my old jobs for keeping track of fMRI datasets. It's best used for large data though, so one may want to find something similar but perhaps better aligned for what they need.